# how to code 3x3 matrix gradient in C++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, matrix

[matrix gradient](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPKWO.png)

how to code in C++ to solve the question of the picture???
Thanks for everyone's answering!!!

Comment: You need to show us some effort first - please read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int A[3][3];
    for (int i =0; i<3 ;i++){
        for(int j=0; j<3; j++){
            cin >> A[i][j];
        }
    }
    int d = A[0][0]*(A[1][1]*A[2][2] - A[1][2]*A[2][1]) - A[0][1]*(A[1][0]*A[2][2] - A[1][2]*A[2][0]) + A[0][2]*(A[1][0]*A[2][1] - A[1][1]*A[2][0]);
    cout << d << endl;
}
```